# Emoji don't knit to PDF

Tags: pdf, knitr, r-markdown, emoji, xelatex

If I run `cat("\U001F615")` on the command line in RStudio on my Mac, it shows the emoji. But if I knit it (Rmd) into a pdf, I get this error message:

> ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with
>   LaTeX.
>
> See the inputenc package documentation for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> l.144 \end{verbatim}

Try running pandoc with `--latex-engine=xelatex`.
pandoc:

> Error producing PDF Error: pandoc document conversion failed with
>   error 43 Execution halted

But if I do `latex_engine: xelatex`, I don't get an error message, but the knitted pdf still doesn't show the emoji. Can someone help me in how I can knit to PDF with Emoji displaying?

Answer (score 0):

There is a LaTeX package that adds support for emoji here: https://github.com/alecjacobson/coloremoji.sty

I haven't had any luck installing it though, because it's not on CTAN yet and I'm a LaTeX noob!

Once it's installed, you can add something like this to your YAML header:

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Me"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{coloremoji}
output:
    pdf_document
---
```

Comment: I am having a lot of issues using `coloremoji.sty` on MacOS X